# using Aerospike CE to replicate a DB on 3 VPS for the same data center, without XDR

Tags: aerospike

For a startup-company project, we are renting three linux servers from the same datacenter in France (from OVH).

We are using three VPS at the moment. We will later switch to dedicated servers in case of commercial success.

We want to install a replicated distributed database on these 3 VPS, using a replication factor of 2 to allow a minimum of fault-tolerance.

If possible, we'd like to use Aerospike, as we prefer it over MongoDB and CouchDB.

So my question is : is it possible to use Aerospike Community Edition to replicate the database records across these 3 VPS, without XDR ? And how can we achieve that ?

Answer (score 4):

Sure,  XDR is only needed for replication across datacenters. To replicate within a cluster in a datacenter, configure your namespace's [replication-factor](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#replication-factor) to the desired value.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for the quick aswer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your data replicated on two separate but identical configuraton Aerospike clusters (clusterA with 3 VSPS, clusterB with 3 VSPs) (Is what you are asking for?) on CE without using XDR, you can instantiate two client objects in your application, use one clientA object to write to clusterA, use the other clientB object to repeat the operation to the other clusterB. You will have a performance hit but may work for you.

If you just have one cluster of 3 VSPs, setting replication factor of two in your namespace configuration automatically keeps one master record and one replica on the same cluster, record level data evenly distributed across the cluster, with master and replica of any record always on different nodes.

Comment: Smart !!! I'll evaluate the manual replication between clusters too, to compare its performance to automatique replicationn within a single cluster. Tnx for the idea :)

Comment: You need good housekeeping to always keep your application mirrored to both clients. If you forget to keep them synced while making some changes, the data set will diverge and you could miss it - then hard to recover. With XDR, Aerospike handles that for you by maintaining a circular buffer of digest log of all updates and shipping them to remote cluster.